# Running WMI Query results in COMException (0x80080005)

Tags: c#, wmi

I have been working on a small WMI Info grabber for my job as I work with hundreds of servers and being able to grab certain information can be quite beneficial when having to get it on more than 5 servers.

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM ComputerSystem");

ManagementObjectSearcher objectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ServerConnect.HardwareScope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection retObject = objectSearcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject manObj in retObject)
{
    string[] data = ((string)manObj["Description"]).Split('-');
    string IPMI = data[1].Substring(7);
    string firmware = data[2].Substring(5);

    output.Add("IPMI Version: " + IPMI);
    output.Add("BMC Firmware Version: " + firmware);
}

return output;
```

This is currently what I am using to grab some basic data from the ComputerSystem, this which works on some servers but crashes on others obtains the correct information that I am wanting; however, I need to prevent it from crashing with a COMException.

It says it breaks out with the System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException at the following line of code:

```
foreach (ManagementObject manObj in retObject)
```

I have been trying to solve this issue as to why some servers get this exception returned rather than being able to grab the information and if it is possible to fix it.

I have been trying to fix this for the last couple weeks and have finally decided to ask for help about this specific problem that I am having.

**UPDATE**

I have ran the same name space and selection for the servers giving me issues in WMI Code Creator ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8572 ) and it is able to obtain the data I need however when ran through my program it gives the COMException. I have gone over the code that Code Creator makes, and my code and have modified some of it and it still gives me the error.

Comment: Sounds like you may have one of several issues, 1st thing that comes to mind would be the machine where you are having issues, does it expect credentials such as `username/password` before Invoking WMI calls? `2nd` is WMI installed and or setup on the Remote Servers that are not working? `3rd` What is the difference in the OS` from the Working Remote Server(s) vs the Non Working Remote Server(s)?

Comment: I'm going to take an (somewhat) educated guess and say it is permissions related. Take a look at the account you are using to execute this code and make sure it has admin level permissions.

Comment: 1. I am using credentials however I am able to connect to the server but it freezes upon running the command above and than crashes with the COMException.

2. WMI is installed and enabled on all servers

3. Every server is a Windows Server 2012 OS

@EkoostikMartin All the servers have the same admin permission levels and I log in with the admin account. Following are the levels I am using which works on every server but the ones with this error:
conOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

Comment: Running your code it fails do you have another WMI Query you could run instead..? to test?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Are you running it correctly? Because I know it works successfully on some servers but crashes on others here is an image showing it completing a query on a server. Running the exact code in the original post.

http://puu.sh/2PtUd.png

Comment: and this is the actual query `"SELECT * FROM ComputerSystem"` you are running.. because using your code I get `Class Not Found Error`

Comment: Are you looking for "ComputerSystem" in the right scope? This is not under "\root\cimv2" this class is under "\root\Hardware"

Comment: It appears that you are doing something different than I am are you missing code that you are not showing..?

Comment: I have a class that controls the connection to the server after it is connected I choose a command to run, in this case function List<string> GetBMCFirmware() which runs through EVERYTHING in the original post, there is no code missing.
is the scope that it is being connected into for access to the ComputerSystem Class
ManagementScope("\\\\" + serverIP + "\\root\\Hardware", conOptions);

The only code I am not showing is the part where it connects to the server and sets up the management scope. Which does not fail anywhere hence why I am not including it.

Comment: I get `NameSpace not found "\root\Hardware"` I wonder if it's an OS problem I can get connection to work if I point to `\root\cimv2`

Comment: Updated the Original Post with an update. I ran the WMI Code Creator and connected to the server through that and it worked successfully however on my program it didn't.